# Using a secured Spring Data Rest RepositoryRestResource from Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a simple `@RepositoryRestResource` that exposes a REST interface for a `User` object. My repo also includes a custom method for finding a `User` by email address. I'm using `@PostAuthorize` to restrict access to only the logged in user.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @PostAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') OR principal.id == returnObject.id")
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email")
    User findUserByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

I also want to use `UserRepository.findUserByEmail` inside my `UserDetailsService` for auth.

```
  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
      User user = userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
```

Since `findUserByEmail` is annotated with `PostAuthorize` my `UserDetailsService` is throwing an auth exception due to there not being a principal available.

Is there any way to use a secured and exported `@RepositoryRestResource`'s from Java code?

Comment: did you found the solution for this ?